# Is it possible to execute a for loop inside a display list in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a pattern using multiples calls to a ellipse function, that draws the feature like this:

```
 glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i=0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        //convert degrees into radians
        float degInRad = i*DEG2RAD;
        glVertex2f(cos(degInRad)*xradius,sin(degInRad)*yradius);
    }
glEnd();
```

To accelerate the rendering I decided put everything on a display list and created the following function that is called by main() :

```
void features::drawEllipse(float xradius, float yradius, GLuint index)
{
    glNewList(index, GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for(int i=0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            //convert degrees into radians
            float degInRad = i*DEG2RAD;
            glVertex2f(cos(degInRad)*xradius,sin(degInRad)*yradius);
        }
        glEnd();
    glEndList();
}
```

But there is no evidence of better performance when I do the call on main

```
static GLuint ellipseList;
...
drawEllipse(0.2,0.3,ellipseList);
```

What am I doing wrong or is that a for loop is not allowed inside display lists?

Comment: How is `ellipseList` in `main()` supposed to get updated if `drawEllipse()`'s `index` is passed by value?  Where's your `glCallList()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL display lists don't care about loops or any other programming constructs. Essentially they're just a recording of every **OpenGL** function called, in sequence, that happen between *glNewList* and *glEndList*. It's kind of as if you surrounded every function beginning with *gl…* (and only those) with a *print* statement that prints into some kind of file. When calling the display list, just the contents are "played back". Any loops that are used when building a display lists are only as effective as putting a loop around calls to *printf* – essentially the same effect.

As why you don't see a performance difference? Because with modern GPUs the driver has to compile the calls to *glVertex* and its friends (the immediate mode drawing calls) into a command buffer that gets submitted to the GPU anyway. And this command buffer is not so different to what's in the display list itself. If the amount of calls to *glVertex* goes up, you'll see the effect of the function call and memory allocation overhead, though. Try replacing that 360 with some *large* number, like 1000000.